# Python Beautiful Soup Error Extracting src

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract some images from a website and save the scr links to a text file. However I am getting blank text file when running following code:

```
with open("links.txt", "r") as a_file:
  for line in a_file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(stripped_line).text, "html.parser")
    completeName = os.path.join(workingpath, stripped_line + ".txt")
    with open(completeName, "w") as f_out:
        for inp in soup.select('#main img'):
            print(inp.attrs["src"], sep="\n", file=f_out)
            print (inp.attrs["src"])
```

Comment: This page gives a ```403``` status code using ```beautifulsoup```

Comment: What does that mean? The page is opening perfectly on my browser

Comment: I tried with selenium as well - That means the page is Forbidden. It uses Cloudfare security to prevent automated software running on it. You can only access the page using a browser.

Comment: What about using user-agent. Is it possible in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work.

Comment: Any workaround?

Comment: Normally you'd want to avoid b4s by using API's, particularly for these kind of scenario's where scraping attempts are actively blocked. There will be alternatives but those are more intensive (like setting up a macro and using browser interaction for example). I would suggest asking the website if they have an API for you to plug into. Makes life loads easier too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for a workaround, here is a solution using Selenium and BeautifulSoup:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "place your url here"
options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("user-agent=Chrome/80.0.3987.132")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)

driver.get(url)

file1=open('links.txt','w')

html_source=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_source,'lxml')

#finding all images
images=soup.find_all('div',class_='box-image')

for image in images:
    #for each image append the src attribute to links.txt
    file1.write(image.find('img')['src'])
    file1.write('\n')

file1.close()
driver.quit()
```